# Get the day from a very simple date

Tags: php, date

Is there a simple way to get the day from a very simple date string?

For example:

```
14 mar 2012
```

gets converted to:

```
Wed, 14 mar 2012
```

Comment: [`strtotime()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+parse+date

Answer (score 3):

You should familiarize yourself with [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime):

```
$str = "14 mar 2012";
```

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("j M Y", $str);
$str = $date->format("D, j M Y");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$dateUnformated = '14 mar 2012';

$dateFormated = date("D, j M Y", strtotime($dateUnformated));
```